# Redirect WordPress User based on user role when accessing a page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to create a simple redirect when someone tries accessing a certain page depending on user role.

I've created a site with membership functionality that offers certain things to paid members. Free members can only access one page after login but if they know the URL to the paid area they can see the content. I was wondering if there's a way to create a 301 redirect so that when the free member tries to go on the paid page, it redirects them back to the free area.

Is this possible? If you need more info, please ask!

Thanks
David

Comment: Which plugin have you used for membership?

Comment: Hi Rajat,

I've used user role editor, woocommerce and gravity forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try like this and make it more wordpress friendly.

```
function role_redirections() {
$loggedin_user = wp_get_current_user();  
if (!is_user_logged_in() || !in_array( 'memorial_user', (array) $loggedin_user->roles )) {
    $location1 =  get_option( 'siteurl' ) .'/member-portal/';
    header('Location: '.$location1.'');
    } 
}
add_action('wp_head', 'role_redirections');
```

Comment: Thank's very much! I'll use this instead.

Answer (score 1):

paste this code into your activate theme or chilled theme function.php file

```
function role_redirections() {
    $logedin_user = wp_get_current_user();  
    if (!is_user_logged_in() || !in_array( 'shop_manager', (array) $logedin_user->roles )) {
        $location1 =  home_url();
        header('Location: '.$location1.'');
    } 
}
add_action('wp_head', 'role_redirections');
```

Comment: Thanks Rajat, I will try this and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hi Rajat, yeah I got that, I will change "shop manager" to match the user role name that I am using.

Answer (score 1):

@rajat.gite

I tried you answer but it didn't quite work how I wanted so I modified the code as below:

```
function role_redirections() {
$loggedin_user = wp_get_current_user();  
if (!is_user_logged_in() || !in_array( 'memorial_user', (array) $loggedin_user->roles )) {
    $location1 =  'https://www.myswansong.com/member-portal/';
    header('Location: '.$location1.'');
    } 
}
add_action('wp_head', 'role_redirections');
```

The only real difference is amending the home_url(); to a string with the full URL I need.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The way you used for URL its a hard coded it is better to use wordpress function :  home_url('member-portal');